# Rotating uiview and all its contents

Tags: xcode, uiview, uiimageview, transform, rotatetransform

UPDATE: iOS 8 fixes is issue and scales the rotated view properly. A workaround for iOS 7 is by increasing the frame width and height since it decreases both.

I am trying to rotate a uiview. The uiview contains a uiimageview in it. This is the code I have so far.

```
#define DegreesToRadians(x) ((x) * M_PI / 180.0)
self.backImageFrame.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(-5));
self.backImageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
self.backImageFrame.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

This is the result I get. I am trying to fix the uiimageview inside as you can tell it goes out the uiview. I would like it inside it.

[image]

After adding

```
self.backImageFrame.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

I get this result is there anyway to get it to have an indent like the left side.

[image]

Looking for this but rotated

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hmm well, as u told u are using a view, u are adding like below hierarchy

```
 uiview->imageview
```

in the above uiview is the rotating view and the image view is the image view contains the image

so there might be wrong in setting the autoresizing part, first disable the auto layout then set the image view Autoresizing to like below image.

[image]

then use the code

```
self.rotatingView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(-5));//hear rotating view is the view contains the image view 

self.rotatingView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `clipToBounds = YES;`

Comment: Try also setting `maskToBound = YES` on the `layer` property. Also what is the `imageview` (dog) frame compared to the parent frame. Is it padded - left/right/top/bottom? e.g `parent frame = {0,0,100,100}`, `image frame = {10,10,80,80}`